# Access last string after split function to create new list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, split, list-manipulation

I am a beginner in Python and I have been working on a code to access two types of files (dcd and inp files), combine them and create a new list with the matching strings.

I got stuck somewhere at the beginning. I want to get all dcd files here. So they have .dcd extension but the first part is not the same. So I was thinking if there is a way to access them after I have split the string.

```
    #collect all dcd files into a list
list1 = []
for filename1 in glob.glob('*/FEP_SYAF014*/FEP1/298/*/*.dcd'):
    filename1 = filename1.split('/')
    filename1.sort()    
    list1.append(filename1)
```

I want to get only names with dcd extension that are indexed [5] and create a new list or mutate this one, but I am not sure how to do that.

p.s I have just posted first part of the code 
Thank you ! 
[the oddly sorted part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT5jI.png)
[this one looks better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dymTE.png)

and this is how I would like it to look like, but sorted and without eq* files. 
[want this sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYM36.png)

Comment: `filename1.sort()` is sorting the file parts... are you sure?

Comment: what is your expected output? it's not clear.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I want to get all dcd files here. So they have .dcd extension but the first part is not the same. So I was thinking if there is a way to access them after I have split the string. Oh and it is sorting files

Comment: how do you want to sort? according to full filepath, or just by filename?

Comment: It would be great if I could sort it by the file name. I just did not know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked. I just added del filename1[:5] to get rid of other unnecessary string parts 
    import os, glob
    list1 = sorted(glob.glob('*/FEP_SYAF014*/FEP1/298/*/*.dcd'), key = os.path.basename)

```
for filename1 in sorted(glob.glob('*/FEP_SYAF014 */FEP1/298/*/*.dcd'),key = os.path.basename):
    filename1 = filename1.split('/')

    filename1.sort()
    list1.append(filename1)
    del filename1[:5]
    print filename1
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `sort` with a sort key: `os.path.basename` (extracts only the basename of the file to perform sort):

```
import os, glob
list1 = sorted(glob.glob('*/FEP_SYAF014*/FEP1/298/*/*.dcd'), key = os.path.basename)
```

Comment: Now it is sorted but I still get this 
['1', '2.water', '298', 'FEP1', 'FEP_SYAF014-19a', 'md_1000_0000.dcd'] and I only want md_* part

Comment: my code is supposed to _replace_ your loop, not to be in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function is applied to file name parts. This is not what you want. If I understand well you want to sort the filename list, not the parts of the filename.

The code given by Jean François is great but I guess you'd like to get your own code working.

You need to extract the file name by using only the last part of the split

A split returns a list of strings. Each item is a part of the original.

filename = filename.split ('/')[len (filename.split ('/'))-1]

This line will get you the last part of the split
Then you can add that part to your list
And after all that you can sort your list

Hope this helps!